# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix - Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new to java and android. I need some help with my main.xml file.
here is the error i have - error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
    - Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
     or "/>".
    - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
here is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
EditText  
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    andtoid:text="New To Do Item"  
    EditText>  
ListView  
    android:id="@+id/myListView"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    andtoid:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

the error is with the edit text.
thanks for all the help you can give
cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your XML, here is a proper one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="New To Do Item" />
    <ListView  
        android:id="@+id/myListView"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

And sometimes you used "andtoid" instead of "android".

I think you will also get an error (later) because your ListView should use `android:id="@id/android:list"`.

Comment: can you tell me the other errors so i know what to watch out for pleasw

Comment: Try to copy/paste my code, in yours you wrote "andtoid" instead of "android" and I think this is why you get this error

Comment: thank you you have been so helpful you answered another question of mine thanks

Answer (score 0):

If that's actually how your XML looks, you seem to be missing a bunch of > and < symbols.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="New To Do Item">
    </EditText>  
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/myListView"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```